# Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/application/ApplicationStateListener" while deploying application into Weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Getting NoClassDefFoundError after adding listener "ADFApplicationStateListener" in weblogic-appliations.xml.

Earlier weblogic-applications.xml has listener "ADFApplicationLifecycleListener". I am able to deploy the application with this listener.
But as per the mandates specified in the section "**Custom ADF application Deployment requirements**" of JDeveloper documentation in the below link, I have configured with the "ADFApplicationStateListener" listener.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/121200-rn-1917713.html

How can I resolve this error ?

Thanks,
Gopal.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/application/ApplicationStateListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.findClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:101)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:86)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow$CreateListenerAction.run(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:140)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow$BaseAction.invoke(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:104)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.HeadLifecycleFlow.createListener(HeadLifecycleFlow.java:117)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationStateListener is introduced in Weblogic server as part of following bug fix :-

Here the bug is there is no callback for cleanup the ADF resources while stopping the application in weblogic server.
Actually postStop() method of ApplicationLifecycleListener will do this while removal or undeployment of the application.

But when an application requires only restart, i.e stop the application and start it again (no need to undeploy & deploy) then there is no callback for ADF MDS related resources cleanup. 
So, ApplicationStateListener is introduced to have a callback for resource cleanup while stopping the application.

My Weblogic server(version 10.3.6.0) is not applied with the patch (patch 56MM) which has the above bug fix.

So, if want to continue with ApplicationStateListener I have to apply the patch, otherwise I have to continue with the ApplicationLifecycleListener.